# Woocommerce redirect loop error when deleting product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have set a custom template for the woocommerce cart page. Every thing works fine like updating product etc.

But when i remove any product from the cart the blank page appears. Hold for sometimes and then an error occurs that says 'This page has a redirect loop'.

When i manually go to the cart page again there are so many notifications of 'Cart Updated' Seems that it runs multiple time. However that product deleted successfully without effecting any other thing in the cart page.

Below is the link for the delete product.

```
<a href="http://localhost:7777/xyx/?page_id=122&amp;remove_item=b3e3e393c77e35a4a3f3cbd1e429b5dc&amp;_wpnonce=ccc50ab307" class="remove" title="Remove this item">×</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try: `global $woocommerce; $removeUrl = $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url();` and echo the link in your anchor tag.

Comment: In your custom cart template setup your variable in the loop like so: <?php global $woocommerce; $removeUrl = $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url(); ?> and then add your link like so: <a href="<?php echo $removeUrl; ?>">remove from cart</a> :)

Comment: Nah ! my template just says echo `the_content();`

Comment: can you let me know the reason so i'll find the way to fix. Acutally i have already messed up with wordpress because of one page theme i converted.

Comment: I did what you have told and its making no effect. Even the url is same in both cases.